# Eslint parsing Error: cannot read tsconfig.json

Tags: json, typescript, eslint

i have such structure of my dirs:

```
-projects
  --MyProject
    ---MyDir
      tsconfig.json
      eslinttrc.json
```

in my eslinttrc.json i have

```
  "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
        "sourceType": "module"
    }
```

and also in this dir i have tsconfig.json but eslint gives me an error
"cannot read project\tsconfig.json" - and that because lint is starting search from wrong root dir "projects" not from "MyDir"
And if i point in parseOption path like "***/MyDir/tsconfig.json" - eslint will find right way

How to fix my  parseOption project path to from '**/MyDir/tsconfig.json' to ./tsconfig.json'

Answer (score 3):

You have probably found an answer already, but if this appears again adding

> `project: path.join(__dirname, "tsconfig.eslint.json")`

to your `.eslintrc.js` file helps. [Have a look at this Github thread for reference](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1170#issuecomment-811871985)